# Как достать дату из CalendarView и пустить её гулять дальше по базе данных?

Tags: java, android, calendar-view

сразу покажу код

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText edTitle, edDisc;
private CalendarView dateTime;
private String datetime ;
private MyDbManager myDbManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    init();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    myDbManager.OpenDb();
}
private void init(){
    myDbManager = new MyDbManager(this);
    edTitle = findViewById(R.id.edTitle);
    edDisc = findViewById(R.id.edDisc);
    dateTime = findViewById(R.id.dateTime);
}


public void onClickSave (View view){

    dateTime.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year,int month, int dayOfMonth2) {
            datetime = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth2;
        }
    });

    String title = edTitle.getText().toString();
    String disc = edDisc.getText().toString() ;

    if (title.equals("") || disc.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.text_empty,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        myDbManager.insertToDb(title,disc,datetime);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        myDbManager.closeDb();
    }
}
```

}
не получается достать дату из слушателя setOnDateChangeListener, мне нужна дата в String, как можно это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ставите слушатель после клика по кнопке, но он срабатывает только после изменения даты - соответственно остальному коду обработчика кнопки актуальная дата не доступна.
Либо перенесите в `init()`, либо уберите слушатель вообще и под кнопкой берите дату непосредственно из `CalendarView`

```java
private void init(){
    myDbManager = new MyDbManager(this);
    edTitle = findViewById(R.id.edTitle);
    edDisc = findViewById(R.id.edDisc);
    dateTime = findViewById(R.id.dateTime);

    // либо ставим слушатель заранее при инициализации,
    // но поле datetime мы должны будем проверить перед использованием -
    // присвоено ли ему значение.
    dateTime.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year,int month, int dayOfMonth2) {
            datetime = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth2;
        }
    });
}


public void onClickSave (View view){
    // либо получаем дату из CalendarView когда она нам понадобилась
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTimeInMillis(dateTime.getDate());
    int year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dayOfMonth = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    datetime = year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth;

    String title = edTitle.getText().toString();
    String disc = edDisc.getText().toString() ;

    if (title.equals("") || disc.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.text_empty,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        myDbManager.insertToDb(title,disc,datetime);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        myDbManager.closeDb();
    }
}
```